# Identifying which user connected via AD group in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

Using SQL server 2008r2 or 2012.

I've been searching but haven't found an answer, apparently my google-foo is weak.
I need to find out which users in an AD Group having been logging into my SQL servers.  We are trying to audit user logins to see both how long user accounts have been inactive and to see how many licenses we will need coming up.  I can get all the other information, the only thing I can't find is what users in each group have been logging in.

Any help locating where I can find this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

AD Group contains many logins included and many people may use same login to log into SQLServer..

So you can't distinctly find  which users in an AD Group having been logging into SQL servers

One more approach would be to use

```
select client_net_address from sys.dm_exec_connections
```

each user would have a disinct ip when logged from distinct machine.Gather this data over a period and try to get unique count of user logins

Comment: The count of users doesn't help as I am trying to find the individuals who will need MSDN licenses to connect.  I think just using the machine login IP will not help as much, especially if they are using a jump box to connect in with.  Appreciate the idea though.